# Can my employer see my private google account history when just logging in and out in a matter of 10 seconds on a work laptop (REPOSTED)

Tags: privacy, account-security, logging

So I did this post before on a guest account but I had further questions so now I'm posing it on a real one.

Can my employer see my private google history/”google activity” if I didn’t do anything on my work pc? For some context I logged in to my private google account on my work computer just to send a pdf file I couldn’t send on my phone. I logged into my google account on microsoft edge, but in private/incognito mode. But I was only logged in for about like 10 seconds because when I went to “google.com” I saw my previous searches from another device appear as recomendations on what to search. Note that google sync is disabled so that shouldn't happen, but appearntly google web and app activity still auto-completles your searches based on your previous google searhes across all devices. I instantly changed password and logged out. I didn't know that “google activity” has an option that gives the opportunity to see the search history of the account no matter what device you’re logged in on if it's enabled if you go to "https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity". I also saw that edge had some kind of extention that allowed all data to be read by the work organisation. The recomendations for autocomplete searches only came up on the site “google.com” for some more context, and nowhere else. So my Question is, Even though I didn’t search anything or do anything on my google account, can my employer/work still see/download my previous history stored on my google account or anything like that because I logged in on the work computer? I really was only signed in for maximum of like 10-15 seconds and I never checked my history while being logged in there. I just don’t want to get in trouble if I ever googled something unpopular.

Also even though I switched passwords and anything could my employer still see and access new activity on my google account even though I logged out and switched passwords? I mean, is it somehow now connected to their servers and did my google account just become an account associated to them in some way?

Comment: Same question. Same answer.

Comment: Jack - using the Contact Us link, you can request SE merge your accounts if you want